# sample_weight parameter shape error in scikit-learn GridSearchCV

Tags: scikit-learn, keras, grid-search

Passing the sample_weight parameter to GridSearchCV raises an error due to incorrect shape. My suspicion is that cross validation is not capable of handling the split of sample_weights accordingly with the dataset.

## First part: Using sample_weight as a model parameter works beautifully

Let's consider a simple example, first without GridSearch:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


dataURL = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mcasl/PAELLA/master/data/sinusoidal_data.csv'

x = pd.read_csv(dataURL, usecols=["x"]).x
y = pd.read_csv(dataURL, usecols=["y"]).y
occurrences = pd.read_csv(dataURL, usecols=["Occurrences"]).Occurrences
my_sample_weights = (1 - occurrences/10000)**3
```

`my_sample_weights` contains the importance that I assign to each observation in x, y, as the following picture shows. The points of the sinusoidal curve get higher weights than those forming the background noise.

```
plt.scatter(x, y, c=my_sample_weights>0.9, cmap="cool")
```

[image: Color coded dataset with respect to my_sample_weights]

Let's train a neural network, first without using the information contained in `my_sample_weights`:

```
def make_model(number_of_hidden_neurons=1):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(number_of_hidden_neurons, input_shape=(1,), activation='tanh'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
    model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mse')
    return model

net_Not_using_sample_weight = make_model(number_of_hidden_neurons=6)
net_Not_using_sample_weight.fit(x,y, epochs=1000)

plt.scatter(x, y, )
plt.scatter(x, net_Not_using_sample_weight.predict(x), c="green")
```

As the following picture shows, the neural network tries to fit the shape of the sinusoidal but the background noise prevents it from a good fit.
[image]

Now, using the information of `my_sample_weights` , the quality of the prediction is a much better one.
[image]

## Second part: Using sample_weight as a GridSearchCV parameter raises an error

```
my_Regressor = KerasRegressor(make_model)

validator = GridSearchCV(my_Regressor,
                     param_grid={'number_of_hidden_neurons': range(4, 5),
                                 'epochs': [500],
                                },
                     fit_params={'sample_weight': [ my_sample_weights ]},
                     n_jobs=1,
                    )
validator.fit(x, y)
```

Trying to pass the sample_weights as a parameter gives the following error:

```
...
ValueError: Found a sample_weight array with shape (1000,) for an input with shape (666, 1). sample_weight cannot be broadcast.
```

It seems that the sample_weight vector has not been split in a similar manner to the input array.

For what is worth:

```
import sklearn
print(sklearn.__version__)
0.18.1

import keras
print(keras.__version__)
2.0.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We developed PipeGraph, an extension to Scikit-Learn Pipeline that allows you to get intermediate data, build graph like workflows, and in particular, solve this problem (see the examples in the gallery at [http://mcasl.github.io/PipeGraph](http://github.com/mcasl/PipeGraph) )

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that as a standard, the GridSearch uses 3-fold cross-validation, unless explicity stated otherwise. This means that 2/3 data points of the data are used as training data and 1/3 for cross-validation, which does fit the error message. The input shape of 1000 of the fit_params doesn't match the number of training examples used for training (666). Adjust the size and the code will run.

```
my_sample_weights = np.random.uniform(size=666)
```

Comment: Just to elaborate - length of sample weight array needs to be the same as full training set (not size of each cv set), after train/test split.